# Create a text file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, text-files

I'm trying to create a text file using javascript (online) with the following code:

```
   <html>
<head>
<script>
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("profile/test.txt", True);
    s.writeline("HI");
    s.writeline("Bye");
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>To sign up for the Excel workshop please fill out the form below:
</p>
<form onsubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
Type your first name:
<input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">
<br>Type your last name:
<input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

However, I receive the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

with the set fso line.

I hope someone can help me here

Comment: Where did you get the code from? It seems to be written for IE and VBScript.

Comment: From here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/279385-how-to-create-text-file-using-javascript/

Comment: Actually @fgb you are right, this is solely for use with IE, I gues s I'll have to look for another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `var`, not `set`, wherever you got that.

`var` initializes a variable within the scope where it is initialized. In that case, if you use :

`var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");`

then you're making an `fso` variable accessible inside the `WriteToFile` function.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that got rid of the errors, I thought set was some type of specific thing js had for file creating but I guess not, anyway, the code still doesn't work!